# 400 Bad request using Axios to call API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios

I'm trying to call a stock quote API with my token on iexcloud.io, and it's pretty normal when I use my browser and Postman to send a get request, but when I send a get request with Axios, it keep telling me it's a 400 bad request. Is there any way to fix this?

```
const axios = require('axios')
const financeAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/TSLA/quote?token=pk_6f07fecf2a3a480482da128abc39f27e',
})
const getStock = () => financeAPI.get(`/`)
const apis = {getStock}

module.exports = apis
```

```
async function doWork() {
    try {
      await api.getStock().then((result) => {console.log(result.data)})
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  
doWork()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGER7.png

Comment: Your question is more about HTTP than axios. A 400 is the remote server saying 'that request isn't in the format expected'. You might need to add some headers, or a query string, or some other details. What you need to change depends on iexapis.com, nobody else can know. I would check the documentation for the API at iexapis.com

Comment: Also: `const result = await api.getStock(); console.log(result.data)` (you don't need `when` if you're using `await` - and `await` is much better!)

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you get a bad request it means you are using the api endpoint with a wrong format, for example, verify the token you are sending needs to be send as an url param.